# How can I install php_posix php extension in windows?

Tags: php

I'm trying to play with symfony in windows, and when I run the check configuration script gives me the next error:

```
[[WARNING]] The posix_isatty() is available: FAILED
        *** Install and enable the php_posix extension (used to colorized the CLI output) ***
```

how can I install the php_posix in windows or it's not possible to install in windows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The POSIX extension cannot be installed on Windows as stated on https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php.

> **Note:** This extension is not available
> on Windows platforms.

The Windows shell doesn't support color. If you want to play around with Symfony MVC Framework on Windows, you may need to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) (or something similar).

Comment: @j2gl Note that what you're seeing is just a warning from the configuration checker, not a show-stopping error. Symfony works just fine on Windows (without the colorised CLI output.) You'll just have to live with black and white output from the command line.

Comment: There are ANSI drivers for the Windows shell. Is that the only reason POSIX won't install? https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases

Answer (score 5):

For colorized output support in Windows, you have two options, ansicon and cygwin. However Symfony2 will only auto-colorize if ANSICON env variable. In cygwin you have to set the variable in ~/.bash_rc.

Bonus: Also download puTTYCyg for cygwin.